# Does Rails 3.1 support conditional PUT like it does conditional GET?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rest

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to learn to what extent Rails supports conditional GET and conditional PUT using HTTP e-tags.

It seems Rails' "fresh?" method supports conditional GET (If-None-Match header), but not conditional PUT (If-Match header). It seems this is because "fresh?" uses "etag_matches?", which only looks at the If-None-Match header.

Having read the source code, I guess I can implement conditional PUT myself. I was just wondering if Rails supports this out of the box in a way I haven't found yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Accept some more questions! 27% is low

Comment: I didn't realize. Thanks, done!

Comment: Why would you want this to work? If you're PUT'ing data to the server or updating a record, you would want rails to accept that data, right? not ignore it b/c of an e-tag.

Comment: @Jesse Wolgamott: because e-tags are not only for caching, but also for concurrency control. If someone has updated the resource on the server since the client has read it, the update should not succeed if you care about proper concurrency control.

Comment: I should add that I'm using Rails for API development, not for web site development.

Comment: Decently sure you're going to have to implement yourself -- haven't seen anything like that to date in rails.

Comment: Having looked through the source code some more, I tend to agree. If you post this as an answer instead of a comment, I can accept it if I don't get any contrary answers.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott -- Your answer has remained for over a year and a half, looks like you are correct. Would you mind moving your comment to the answer section? I'll remove my answer once you do. (I can also remove my answer if you're still looking for a better answer and would prefer to leave the question unresolved.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> e-tags are not only for caching, but also for concurrency control. If someone has updated the resource on the server since the client has read it, the update should not succeed if you care about proper concurrency control.

If you're looking to prevent someone from updating a model after another update, you'll need to add this yourself. You can look at the etag and headers yourself, so a helper method is likely the way to go.